# adding a whereBetween clause doesnt return expected result set

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-5, eloquent

Example dataset

```
id,created_at, status, category, c_sub_category
1, 2019-01-02 16:36:06, closed, Issue, Team 1
2, 2019-01-03 18:36:01, closed, Fix, Team 2
```

As you can see there are two `c_sub_category` types so the group by should return two rows. It is currently only returning the first result when I add the `whereBetween` clause

I am using `Laravel 5.6` and `SQLite` I am trying to return certain results between a time frame. The problem is that when I add a `whereBetween` clause on the `created_at` column it is missing results. `created_at` is of type `DateTime`

The `startDate` and `endDate` are carbon instances

```
{
    "startDate": {
        "date": "2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "America/Toronto"
    },
    "endDate": {
        "date": "2019-01-06 23:59:59.999999",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "America/Toronto"
    }
}
```

This query should return two results. I am grouping by `c_sub_category` and there are only two `c_sub_categories` but currently it is returning just 1 result

```
$data  = Tickets
            ::whereBetween('created_at', [$week["startDate"], $week["endDate"]])
            ->where('status', 'closed')
            ->where('category', '!=', 'New Development')
            ->groupBy('c_sub_category')
            ->get();
```

This query without the `whereBetween` clause returning two results which is correct

```
$data  = Tickets
            ->where('status', 'closed')
            ->where('category', '!=', 'New Development')
            ->groupBy('c_sub_category')
            ->get();
```

Other ways I have tried that also don't return the correct result set

```
$data  = Tickets
            ::where(function ($query) use ($week) {
                $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$week["startDate"], $week["endDate"]]);
            })
            ->where('category', '!=', 'New Development')
            ->where('status', 'closed')
            ->groupBy('c_sub_category')
            ->get();

$data  = Tickets
            ::where(function ($query) use ($week) {
                $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$week["startDate"], $week["endDate"]]);
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use ($week) {
                $query->where('category', '!=', 'New Development');
                      ->where('status', 'closed');

            })
            ->groupBy('c_sub_category')
            ->get();
```

Comment: `$week["startDate"]` and `$week["endDate"]` are instances of Carbon or strings?

Comment: Can  you provide a data set for us to play with?

Comment: Are your dates start-of-day and end-of-day?  Carbon lib has helper methods for this.

Comment: `$week["startDate"]` and `$week["endDate"]` are carbon instances. I have updated the post with an example

Comment: Can you give us an example of a row that should be returned by isn't?

Comment: @apokryfos I have added an example dataset with the expected results

Comment: Can you just try to get the `toSql()` instead of `get()`? You'll get the query there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the long date format, not only the date

```
Tickets:whereBetween('created_at', ['2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000', '2019-01-06 23:59:59.999999'])
```

Comment: No, the long date isn't mandatory (Not with the trailing zeros)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
Tickets::where('created_at', '>=','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000')->where('created_at', '<=','2019-01-06 23:59:59.999999');
```